# Calculating the Expectation of the product of Poisson variables in a Poisson Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution

I am trying to understand the relationship between a Poisson process and the Poisson random variable.

I understand that if $N(t)$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, then we can consider $N(t)$ ~ Poisson ($\lambda*t$).

Now, I am confused about the various possible random variables that can arise out of the above process, using different values for the rate $\lambda$.

Suppose I have a Poisson process $N(t)$ with rate $1$ (so $\lambda$ $= 1$).

I would like to start with time $0$, and assume some $t$ and $s$ such that $0 < t < s$

I want to understand the relationship between the random variables $N(t)$ and $N(s)$ here.

For example, to calculate $E[N(t) N(s)]$, can I say that $N(s)$ = $N(t)$ + $N(s-t)$ ?

And then I can calculate $E[N(t) N(s)]$ = $E[N(t) * (N(t) + N(s-t))]$

= $E[N(t)^2 + (N(t) N(s-t))]$

= $E[N(t)^2] + E[N(t) N(s-t)]$

Now, $N(t)$ and $N(s-t)$ are independent, since these are the number of events that occur in the disjoint intervals (0, t) and (t, s).

Am I understanding the properties of the Poisson process correctly here?  Thank you very much in any assistance with learning this.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming!